# GlobalMemoryStatusEx() gives total virtual memory as 127 TeraByte

Tags: c++, windows, memory

why GlobalMemoryStatusEx() gives huge total virtual memory.Does it take into account all the page files that can be created?

System details:

Windows 8.1, 64 bit Process, x64 Processor

```
int main()
{
    MEMORYSTATUSEX mex;
    mex.dwLength = sizeof (mex);

    GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&mex);
    std::cout<<mex.ullTotalVirtual<<" "<<mex.ullAvailVirtual;
}
```

> 140737488224256 140737478111232

EDIT:

I got same result on Windows 10.I am interested in knowing how this `127 TB` figure comes up.Why does the system not take into account that i don't have 127 tb space on my disk?

A 32 bit process on (x64 system) shows only 2gb which is the accessible address limit of a 32 bit process for user mode.Why does it not take into account page files in case of 32 bit process?

Comment: Looks like this gives you a theoretical amount of the process virtual address space, regardless to the actual amount of physical storage available (RAM + page files)

Comment: AFAIR, current hardware implementation of AMD64 limits address bits to 48. Windows gives you half of this just like it did in a 32-bit processor...

Comment: @Malkocoglu That seems to make sense.But then i think this API does not take into account pages.Because even after increasing page files, the value remains same.

Comment: @user3819404: Suppose you are on a 32-bit system. You have 10 GB of swap space. Even if you had all the 32-bit address space to your app, you could not use the whole page file !

Comment: @Malkocoglu At the same time if i have a 64bit process, the api showing me 127 tb is misleading because i do not have that much space.I think it should be documented that this is not taking into account page files.

Comment: @user3819404: Sorry but no, virtual memory is not what you think. By having this much virtual memory, you can mmap a 100 TB file and access whole of it without using any swap space and optimal physical memory...

Comment: It is a very old function, been around forever, running on an OS with capabilities that were never envisioned.  How much *actual* virtual memory you have available is highly unpredictable, it depends on how quickly the OS can grow the paging file.  Time is an important factor, the slower you allocate, the better the odds that growth keeps up.  You can only really know by trying it.  Of course the function cannot reasonable do that, so it punts.

Comment: @Malkocoglu If i have 4 GB of physical ram, and have limited total page file size to 4 GB, Can i access a 100 TB file?

Comment: @user3819404: On a 32-bit system no, because you are limited by your virtual memory size of 2GB. On a 64-bit system yes and swap space is irrelevant for this operation...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589(v=vs.85).aspx):

> You can use the `GlobalMemoryStatusEx()` to determine how much memory your application can allocate without severely impacting other applications.

Comment: I thnk that's system specific @user3819404, but I am not sure.